# SSIS package - Automate monthly refreshed data

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

Can someone help me to automate a SSIS package with the following criteria?

1. Pull data from an URL website. This website uploads monthly Excel sheets with data.
2. The data in the Excel sheets needs to be updated monthly in our SQL Server table.
3. We only need the latest data, so every month we can truncate & refill or do a delta.

Background info:

- There is already a table in our DEV environment that is in place and the necessary data is being populated monthly, however data is incorrect & inconsistent. Our company does not manage the DB, so we do not have control over this. That's why I need to make our own table within the DB so we can efficiently load the correct data.

So far these are the things that I have done to test it out:

- Create the package with a Data Flow Task in VS 2019. Excel Source -> Data Conversion -> OLEDB Destination.
- Package ran perfectly fine, with the exception of one column which data types did not convert correctly. (I will work on this issue)

These are the things I need to do to successfully execute this requirement:

- Automate the execution of the SSIS package by creating a SQL maintenance job which will run monthly.

My questions:

1. How can I automate the process of pulling the data from the official source (Excel sheets)  to our DEV environment on a monthly basis? Or do I have to do this manually?
2. How can I track the changes that were made in the table monthly? I know I have these options but not sure which one is better:

- Configure CDC
- Configure change tracking
- DDL Triggers

Any help and best practices will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How can I automate the process of pulling the data from the official source (Excel sheets) to our DEV environment on a monthly basis? Or do I have to do this manually?

Use a script task. It is extremely very little code:

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.DownLoadFile("URL of file", "where you want the file to go");
```

This assumes you can get out of your dev environment.